# Проблема с комбинированными видами, формами и шаблонами.

Tags: bootstrap, django

**Задумка**: добавить возможность создания постов прямо в главной ленте блога при помощи всплывающего окна модалки (с созданием модалки помог bootstrap).

**Проблема**: один и тот же вид у нас должен и показывать список уже имеющихся постов, и создавать новые посты.

Первая попытка создать вид, который бы наследовал функции и атрибуты от `CreateView` и `ListView` сразу привела к ошибке. Тогда я заменил `CreateView` на `FormView`. Итог: лента постов отображается, но в модалке не отображаются поля формы, а при подтверждении выдаёт

```
AttributeError at /blog/

'BlogView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
Exception Value: 'BlogView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
Exception Location: /home/corwin/.virtualenvs/estate/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py in get_context_data, line 108
```

Виды, форма и шаблон на данный момент выглядят так:

```
class BlogView(ListView , FormView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = '/blog/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): #попытка убрать эту функцию ничего не 
                                          #меняет
        context = super(BlogView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['moment'] = moment
        return context

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'text']

<form action="{% url 'blog:index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: На самом деле, bootstrap тут вообще ни при чём, всё дело в джанговских видах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае проще всего поступить так:

```
class BlogView(FormView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = '/blog/'

    def get_post_list(self):
        return Post.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['moment'] = moment
        context['post_list'] = self.get_post_list()
        return context
```

хотя можно и вьюхи "починить" https://stackoverflow.com/a/9423819/1643053

но я бы рекомендовал использовать вашу уже существующую вьюху создания постов, отправляя на нее данные AJAX`ом с главной. Нужно лишь переделать ее так, чтоб по какому либо url либо по GET параметру она в ответ отдавала JSON с информацией что все ок, либо со списком ошибок.

Comment: Посты почему-то не сохраняются

Comment: Если вы используете FormView они и не сохранятся.

либо используйте CreateView либо переопределите form_valid

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(BlogView, self).form_valid(form)

Comment: Я через `CreateView` сделал. В принципе, всё работает почти так, как и было задумано. Осталось по аналогии добавить редактирование постов и ajax-обработку неверного ввода.

Comment: Я за отдельную view. Логически неправильно, если список зачем-то умеет сохранять другие объекты.

Comment: С одной стороны вы правы. Если сделать отдельный вид, то можно обойтись безо всех этих отягчающих код красивостей вроде модалок и ajax-обработки формы. С другой стороны, мой список умеет расширять сам себя, так что тут никаких логических противоречий нет. Из известных примеров: стена вконтакта является как раз таким вот саморасширяющимся списком, только там методы ввода несколько различаются.